# Can someone explain why the reduce function consoled the following numbers

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am new to Javascript and was learning the reduce function today and going through the examples in Mozzila Developer and I slightly modified one and it gave me a result which I can not comprehend (since I am very new). Can someone pls explain the result here and the "rules" behind it? Thanks

```js
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  return accumulator + currentValue
});

console.log(flattened)
```

Answer: 0, 12, 34, 5

Comment: You should have a look at the polyfill on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) page. The link to the specification is just below that.

Comment: thanks, didn't saw that, but from the look of it, that area is still information overload at this point, maybe in future i can reference that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because reduces method reduces the array to a single value.

In your case, you are adding the `arrays([0,1], [2,3], [4,5])` which return a string

Hence, the accumulator is accumulating the sum of iterated currentValue.

Working:
the loop works in the following steps

1. `accumulator = "0,1"`
2. `accumulator = "0,1" + "2,3"`
3. `accumulator = "0,1" + "2,3" + "4,5"`

readable output = `"0,1 2,3 4,5"`

System Generated Output = `"0,12,34,5"`

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't pass an initial value as the accumulator, the initial value here is the array `[0, 1]`. On each iteration, the operation `accumulator + currentValue` is performed and used as the new accumulator on the next iteration (or, as the entire return value of the `.reduce`, if on the last iteration).

On the first iteration, `[0, 1] + [2, 3]` results in `"0,12,3"`. This is because when non-numbers are used with `+`, they are converted into primitives first, and when arrays are converted to primitives, each item is joined by a comma. So

```
[0, 1] + [2, 3]
// evaluates to
'0,1' + '2,3'
// evaluates to
'0,12,3'
```

On the next iteration:

```
'0,12,3' + [4, 5]
// evaluates to
'0,12,3' + '4,5'
// evaluates to
'0,12,34,5'
```

That's the last iteration, so the final result is `'0,12,34,5'`.

Note that there are *no spaces* - the array items are joined *only* by a comma, not by a comma and a space.